# Amazon RDS - Online only when needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I had a question about Amazon RDS. I only need the database online for about 2 hours a day but I am dealing with quite a large database at around 1gb.

I have two main questions:

1. Can I automate bringing my RDS database online and offline via scripts to save money?
2. When I put a RDS offline to stop the "work hours" counter running and billing me, when I bring it back online will it still have the same content (i.e will all my data stay there, or will it have to be a blank DB?). If so, is there any way around this rather than backing up to S3 and reimporting it every time?

Comment: As pointed out below you can snapshot/delete/restore to "start/stop" your RDS instance. I think it may be easier to just install mysql on an EC2 instance which you can start and stop as needed.

Comment: Shame on Amazon, as of June 2016 there is still no such a feature

Comment: Snapshot is a bad option. Snapshots are stored on S3. So when you create a snapshot you'll be billed for storage. Pretty clever from Amazon not to implement stop/start feature forcing you pay anyhow. For now as of June 2016 it is possible to create `db.t2.micro` instance as a free tier for testing purposes.

Comment: As of June 1 2017, RDS supports starting and stopping instances for most engine types. You can do it through the console or through the CLI. More info is available in the [RDS User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a script that will stop/start/reboot an RDS instance

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage ./startStop.sh lhdevices start

INSTANCE="$1"
ACTION="$2"



# export vars to run RDS CLI
export JAVA_HOME=/usr;
export AWS_RDS_HOME=/home/mysql/RDSCli-1.15.001;
export PATH=$PATH:/home/mysql/RDSCli-1.15.001/bin;
export EC2_REGION=us-east-1;
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/home/mysql/RDSCli-1.15.001/keysLightaria.txt;

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
echo "Usage: $0 {MySQL-Instance Name} {Action either start, stop or reboot}"
echo ""
exit 1
fi


shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $ACTION == 'start' ]]
then
echo "This will $ACTION a MySQL Instance"  
rds-restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot lhdevices 
--db-snapshot-identifier        dbStart --availability-zone us-east-1a     
--db-instance-class db.m1.small 

echo "Sleeping while instance is created"
sleep 10m
echo "waking..."

rds-modify-db-instance lhdevices --db-security-groups kfarrell

echo "Sleeping while instance is modified for security group name"
sleep 5m
echo "waking..."

elif [[ $ACTION == 'stop' ]]
then
echo "This will $ACTION a MySQL Instance" 

yes | rds-delete-db-snapshot dbStart

echo "Sleeping while deleting old snapshot "
sleep 10m

#rds-create-db-snapshot lhdevices --db-snapshot-identifier dbStart

# echo "Sleeping while creating new snapshot "
# sleep 10m
# echo "waking...."

#rds-delete-db-instance lhdevices --force --skip-final-snapshot 
rds-delete-db-instance lhdevices --force --final-db-snapshot-identifier dbStart

echo "Sleeping while instance is deleted"
sleep 10m
echo "waking...."

elif [[ $ACTION == 'reboot' ]]
then
echo "This will $ACTION a MySQL Instance" 
rds-reboot-db-instance lhdevices ;

echo "Sleeping while Instance is rebooted"
sleep 5m
echo "waking...."

else

echo "Did not recognize command: $ACTION"
echo "Usage: $0 {MySQL-Instance Name} {Action either start, stop or reboot}"

fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

Comment: A brief instruction on how to enable it would be nice

Answer (score 30):

If you wish to do this programatically,

1. Snapshot the RDS instance using `rds-create-db-snapshot` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-CopyDBSnapshot.html
2. Delete the running instance using `rds-delete-db-instance` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-DeleteDBInstance.html
3. Restore the database from the snapshot using `rds-restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html

You may also do all of this from the AWS Web Console as well, if you wish to do this manually.

Comment: So he could script those steps into a cron job? Hmm..maybe not, because how could he programmatically know the instance ID of the DB server?

Comment: The instance ID of an RDS instanced is based on what it is named when you create the instance.

Comment: That's my understanding too. So he could script a job that says 1) create snapshot of "i-75gh" then 2) kill "i-75gh"...but where would he restore that snapshot to? He'd have to run the second half of the process (create new instance, note the id, restore snapshot to it) manually, n'est pas? *Then* he'd have to update his snapshot/kill script with the new id. There must be some other way...

Comment: The database DBInstanceId is user-specified. It is not assigned. You are likely thinking of EC2 instance ids. From AWS API Documentation on RDS API: "DBInstanceId—User-supplied database identifier; this is the unique key that identifies a DB Instance". The DBInstanceId is what is passed into most AWS RDS API calls to identify the database you want to interact with

Comment: I was thinking of EC2 instance ids--I'm using Postgres, so haven't had the pleasure of using RDS.

Answer (score 10):

You can start EC2* instances using shell scripts, so I guess that you can as well for RDS. 
(see [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS....html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-CreateDBInstance.html))

But unlike EC2*, you cannot "stop" an RDS instance without "destroying" it. You need to create a DB snapshot when terminating your database. You will use this DB snapshot when re-starting the database.

*EC2 : Elastic Computing, renting a virtual server or a server.

Comment: You can: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-db-instance-stop-and-start-in-amazon-rds/

Answer (score 7):

Amazon recently updated their CLI to include a way to start and stop RDS instances.  [stop-db-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/start-db-instance.html) and [start-db-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/stop-db-instance.html) detail the steps needed to perform these operations.

Comment: Yep! The press release can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Comment: Anyone looking to schedule the stop and start of the instance https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/schedule-amazon-rds-stop-and-start-using-aws-lambda/